# Android barcode scanner using excel as database

Tags: android, excel, database, android-studio, barcode-scanner

I'm making a barcode scanner application(Using Barcode Scanner library and Google Vision) which is using an excel file as database and write into excel file.
Excel database will look like this : "Product name" "Barcode".
When someone using the barcode scanner and it scanned a Barcode and matching with database cell "Barcode" a custom dialog will pop up.
In the custom dialog there is a Textview which will show the product name (Matched row) and here we can put a number and then save it. This save button will insert into an excel file all data("Product Name","Barcode","Quantity").

So my questions are : 1. How to read excel as database which we select?
                      2. How to pop up the custom dialog "onScan"?
                      3. How to insert these datas to the excel we created?

```
   public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    public static String filename;
    public static File file;
    public static RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public static Button buttonsecond;
    public static  Uri fileUri;
    public static String filePath;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    String[] permissionsall = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_second);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        if(checkPermission()){

        }else{

        }

        buttonsecond = findViewById(R.id.ScanBarcode);
        buttonsecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ScanActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.item1:
                createnewFile();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                try {
                    openDatabase();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission(){
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionisNeed = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String permission : permissionsall ){
                result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission);
                if(result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                listPermissionisNeed.add(permission);
            }
        }
            if (!listPermissionisNeed.isEmpty()){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,listPermissionisNeed.toArray(new String[listPermissionisNeed.size()]),REQUEST_CODE);
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            HashMap<String, Integer> permissionResults = new HashMap<>();
            int deniedCOunt = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<grantResults.length;i++){
                if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    permissionResults.put(permissions[i],grantResults[i]);
                    deniedCOunt++;
                }
            }
            if(deniedCOunt == 0)
            {

            }
            else{
                for(Map.Entry<String, Integer > entry : permissionResults.entrySet())
                {
                    String permName = entry.getKey();
                    int permResult = entry.getValue();

                    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,permName)){
                        shownewDialog();
                    }else{
                        showsecondDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void shownewDialog(){

        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        dialog.show();

        Button dialogokbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
        dialogokbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            checkPermission();
            }
        });

        Button dialogcancelbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
        dialogcancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                showsecondDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void showsecondDialog(){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_second_dialog, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        dialog.show();

        Button dialogokbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.secondbuttonOk);
        dialogokbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button dialogcancelbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.secondbuttonCancel);
        dialogcancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void createnewFile(){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.file_creator, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        dialog.show();

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.filecreatortext);

        Button filecreatebutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.filercreatorcreatebutton);
        filecreatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Workbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook();
                Cell cell=null;
                CellStyle cellStyle=wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
                cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                Sheet sheet=null;
                sheet = wb.createSheet("Products");
                Row row =sheet.createRow(0);

                cell=row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("Product Name");
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                cell=row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue("Barcodenumber");
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                cell=row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue("Quantity");
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                sheet.setColumnWidth(0,(10*200));
                sheet.setColumnWidth(1,(10*200));
                sheet.setColumnWidth(2,(10*200));

                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),userInput.getText()+".xls");
                FileOutputStream outputStream =null;

                try {
                    outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
                    wb.write(outputStream);
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,userInput.getText()+" File Created!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,"Couldn't create the file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            dialog.dismiss();}
        });
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("*/*");
        chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        file = new File(fileUri.getPath());

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager=getAssets();
            FileInputStream inputStream = (FileInputStream) assetManager.open(file+"");
            filename = String.valueOf(inputStream);
            Toast.makeText(this, filename + "Opened!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            jxl.Workbook wb = jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);

            jxl.Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
            int row = sheet.getRows();
            int col = sheet.getColumns();
            for (int i=0;i<row;row++){
                for (int c=0;c<col;col++){
                    jxl.Cell z = sheet.getCell(c,i);
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == -1) {
                    fileUri = data.getData();
                    filePath = fileUri.getPath();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}


    public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReader.BarcodeReaderListener{

    private static HSSFWorkbook xlWBook;
    private static HSSFSheet xlSheet;
    private static HSSFRow xlRow;
    private static HSSFCell xlCell;
    private static int row;
    private static int cell;
    private static int column;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onScanned(Barcode barcode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScannedMultiple(List<Barcode> barcodes) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanError(String errorMessage) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraPermissionDenied() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1 and 3 reading and writing excel files in Android can be achieved using Apache POI.
I have seen most people struggle with finding right Jar but no need to download a jar separately simply use below mentioned dependencies.

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.12'
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
}
```

For reading from excel

```
    private void readXml(InputStream fis) {
    //fis is FileInputStream to your excel
    try {

        // Create a workbook using the Input Stream
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        // We now need something to iterate through the cells
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {

                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                String cellValue = "";

                // Check for cell Type
                if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    cellValue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
                } else {
                    cellValue = String.valueOf(myCell.getNumericCellValue());
                }

                // Just some log information
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, cellValue);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

For Writing into excel

```
    private void writeToXml() {
    try {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Users"); //Creating a sheet

        for(int  i=0; i<userProfilesWithFilter.size(); i++){

            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            row.createCell(CELL_INDEX_0).setCellValue(VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_KEEP_ON_1ST_COLUMN);
            row.createCell(CELL_INDEX_1).setCellValue(VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_KEEP_ON_2ND_COLUMN);
        }

        String fileName = "FileName.xlsx"; //Name of the file

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "FolderName");// Name of the folder you want to keep your file in the local storage.
        folder.mkdir(); //creating the folder
        File file = new File(folder, fileName);
        try {
            file.createNewFile(); // creating the file inside the folder
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file); //Opening the file
            workbook.write(fileOut); //Writing all your row column inside the file
            fileOut.close(); //closing the file and done

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Refer https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-read-excel-file-from-website.html

Question 2. Creating a pop up is fairly easy in android. AlertDialog or MaterialDialog can be used.